# onActivityResult() and change orientation in the process

Tags: android, orientation-changes, onactivityresult

I want to share with you some problems that made my app crashed and I can not imagine why exactly it pass and, in my opinion, it must not pass, no having sense.

- Activity A (that had implemented onActivityResult() and startActivityforResult()and basically is Viewpager with 2/3 views with some components in each one)
- Activity B (that have implemented setFinish() and finish() to return back)

This is the process:

1. Start activity A
2. Start activity B from A.
3. Change orientacion of activity B.
4. finish() of activity B and return back to activity A.
5. Crash.

I saw the stacktrace and the crash was inside onActivityResult and it was all variables(int, ArrayList, UI components like ListView, ...) that I had used and, as I see, they lost their references.

The type of error that I get was

> "NullPointerExpection" (int and ListView)
>
> "CursorIndexOutOfBoundException" (ArrayList)

heading this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo

I have to say that if there is not any change of orientation, there is not problems, it is all fine.

I fixed the problem but the resulting code you can imagine. I needed to initialize all of that I had errors including using findViewById() for some UI components that it is very costly doing it. I think that it is mainly by ViewPager because it don't pass with a simple XML (with a LinearLayout e.g.) in activity A. Anyone have similar experience or any explanation for that?

Thanks.

Comment: I've always thought this Android's architecture of destroying an Activity on orientation change is the most stupid thing Google's engineers could have come up with. Am I alone in this one?

Comment: No, you are not. I don't know if in iOS/Windows Phone pass the same but it is very tedious this types of error that it is a little bit difficult to discover.